# std::packaged_task compile error w/ gcc 4.6

Tags: c++, concurrency, c++11, g++, std

I'm trying to launch a function in a thread using `std::packaged_task`

```
Query query; /* protobuf object */        

/* fill Query object */

std::packaged_task<SearchResults(Query&)> task([](Query& q) ->SearchResults {
    index::core::Merger merger;
    return merger.search(q);
    });

std::future<SearchResults> ftr = task.get_future();
std::thread(std::move(task),query).detach();
```

Edit2: Updated the code again to fix errors and included the full error message.

g++-4.6 (on Ubuntu 10.04) is unable to compile the code:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/memory:80:0,
              from ../src/net/QueryConnection.cpp:8:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional: In instantiation of ‘std::_Bind_result<void, 
std::packaged_task<SearchResults(Query&)>(Query)>’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/thread:135:9:   instantiated from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, 
_Args&& ...) [with _Callable = std::packaged_task<SearchResults(Query&)>, _Args = 
{Query&}]’
../src/net/QueryConnection.cpp:77:36:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:1365:7: error: ‘std::_Bind_result<_Result, 
_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::_Bind_result(const std::_Bind_result<_Result, 
_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>&) [with _Result = void, _Functor =   
std::packaged_task<SearchResults(Query&)>, _Bound_args = {Query}, 
std::_Bind_result<_Result, _Functor(_Bound_args ...)> = std::_Bind_result<void, 
std::packaged_task<SearchResults(Query&)>(Query)>]’ declared to take const reference, 
but implicit declaration would take non-const
Build error occurred, build is stopped
```

I've read that this is maybe due to a bug: [gcc-mailinglist](http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org/2011-11/msg00090.html)

I'm new to C++ / C++11 - What would be a good working alternative? I just need to launch a thread that gives me a future, whom `get()`-method is called later in an `boost::asio` async loop.

Comment: One problem is that you've declared the packaged_task as taking no arguments and returning a SearchResults, but the lambda takes a single argument.  I would expect your declaration to be `std::packaged_task<SearchResults(Query&)>`

Comment: Can you actually post the full error message? It seems you posted only half of it. That makes it unintelligible.

Comment: I've changed the code to reflect the missing argument and added the full error message with the updated code. Still lot's of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug in GCC 4.6 (actually a [defect](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3358.html#2067) in the C++11 standard) which I've already fixed in 4.7.

As a workaround you can use `std::async`

```
Query query;
std::future<SearchResults> ftr = std::async([](Query& q) ->SearchResults {
      index::core::Merger merger;
      return merger.search(q);
    }, query);
```

This works OK with GCC 4.6,  and is simpler and safer that creating a `packaged_task` and running it in a detached thread anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if these are the cause of the errors GCC is giving, but they are problematic nonetheless.

```
[=](Query& q){
        index::core::Merger merger;
        return merger.search(q);
}
```

Since this lambda doesn't consist of a single return statement, and no explicit return type was given, it has a `void` return type. I suspect you intended it to return a `SearchResults` object. And it takes a `Query&` parameter, so the appropriate signature for the packaged task would be `SearchResults(Query&)`.

```
[=](Query& q) -> SearchResults {
        index::core::Merger merger;
        return merger.search(q);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried to change it now to:

    `std::packaged_task<SearchResults(Query&)> task([SearchResults]    (Query& q){
        index::core::Merger merger;
        return merger.search(q);
    });`

Comment: @emteh Oh, sorry about that. That's not the proper syntax. I edited it in. I went out to do something else and forgot to write the proper syntax in the answer...

Comment: Thanks, got it fixed. The errors related to that vanished. I still have the orignal error message. The `[=]` vs. `[]` makes no difference  .

Answer (score 0):

The updated code has two problems:

1) The lambda doesn't state it's return type correctly.  The syntax you want is (assuming you don't need to copy any local variables) is :

```
[](Query& q) -> SearchResults {
        index::core::Merger merger;
        return merger.search(q);
}
```

2) Given that the packaged task requires a `Query&`, then you will need to pass a reference to a non-constant Query as the second argument to the `std::thread` constructor, so that it can be passed to the task.

What I can't recall is if you can legally pass a non-constant Query reference properly as the second argument to `std::thread`, or if you will need to use `std::ref(q)` so that it properly passes the second argument by reference.

As written, it's attempting to call the task with no arguments, as indicated by

> /usr/include/c++/4.6/future:1272:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

Comment: `std::thread` will copy the arguments by default, so you do need `std::ref`

Comment: @davs: Thanks fixed it now, that solved some problems. The original error is still there, through.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Thanks, `std::ref(query)` makes no difference through. Still have the `std::bind` related error.